# jQuery validate doesn't validate an input on keyup until it has lost focus once

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form with validation using [jQuery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).  This works perfectly however, my form always contains default values:

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="myname" class="required number error">
```

When a user first changes the values in the input boxes, no validation occurs until the input loses focus. After this first time any keyup / change event inside the input will result in validation.

How can I force the validation to occur on keyup / change ALL the time as opposed to after an initial change.

Answer (score 1):

use "onkeypress" event instead "onchange" event .

Answer (score 1):

Try this block after the `.validate()` function:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if(!$(this).valid()){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick answer put `$('#yourForm input, #yourForm select').live('keyup change', function(e) { })` listener to your form and then check if it's the first time input is affected, and then force validate it by `$('#yourForm").validate();`

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your js part for the `validate()` initialisation ?

Did you try something like

```
$('#your_form input').keyUp(function () {
  $(this).parents('form').validate();
});
```